# Cannot access first tab and sometimes the second when each tab is created by a Class

Tags: python, class, tabs, pyqt5

The following code creates 7 tabs each from a different tab class. When it runs, all tabs are created and it opens with tab 1 selected. Once another tab is clicked, Tab 1 can never be opened again. Tab 2 sometimes can be opened, but most of the time not. All the other tabs can be opened at any time. Can any anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

If I use a single class, create the different creation methods from within this class, and then call each method everything works.

The reason I want to use classes for the tabs is two fold. 1) there will be 10 tabs and each tab will have lots of widgets causing a very long file and 2) I want to be able to use Native Language Services (NLS).

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import (QMetaObject )
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QPushButton, QMainWindow,
                             QHBoxLayout,  QApplication, QTabWidget,
                             QMenuBar, QStatusBar)

from Tab1 import *
from Tab2 import *
from Tab3 import *


class Ui_NFPCinput(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1000, 1000)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 990, 800))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2 = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QRect(300, 930, 641, 41))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
    
        self.GetFile = QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.GetFile.setObjectName("GetFile")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.GetFile)

        self.CancelButton = QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.CancelButton.setObjectName("CancelButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.CancelButton)
        
        self.OkButton = QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.OkButton.setObjectName("OkButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.OkButton)
        
        
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 980, 900))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
      
           
        self.tab0 = Tab1(self.tabWidget)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab0.getTab(), "")  
        
        self.tab1 = Tab2(self.tabWidget)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab1.getTab(), "")
         
        self.tab2 = Tab3(self.tabWidget)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab2.getTab(), "")
        
        self.tab3 = Tab1(self.tabWidget)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab3.getTab(), "")
            
        self.tab4 = Tab2(self.tabWidget)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab4.getTab(), "")
        
        self.tab5 = Tab3(self.tabWidget)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab5.getTab(), "")
        
        self.tab6 = Tab1(self.tabWidget)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab6.getTab(), "") 
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 649, 27))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Tabs Test"))
        self.CancelButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OK"))
        self.OkButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cancel"))
        self.GetFile.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab0.getTab()), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 0"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab1.getTab()), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab2.getTab()), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab3.getTab()), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 3"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab4.getTab()), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 4"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab5.getTab()), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 5"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab6.getTab()), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 6"))
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_NFPCinput()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The template for the tab classes, just change the tab number

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel

class Tab1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tab = QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("Tab1")

        self.label = QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(20, 10, 200, 19))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.setText("")
        
        self.retranslateUi()
        
    def getTab(self):  
        return self.tab
    
    def retranslateUi(self):
        _translate = QCoreApplication.translate
        self.label.setText(_translate( "MainTab","This is Object 1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your Tab1.  You've got an extra level of widgets.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel

class Tab1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        # self.tab = QWidget()
        # self.tab.setObjectName("Tab1")
        self.setObjectName("Tab1")

        # self.label = QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(20, 10, 200, 19))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.setText("")

        self.retranslateUi()

    def getTab(self):
        # return self.tab
        return self                                                                         

    def retranslateUi(self):
        _translate = QCoreApplication.translate
        self.label.setText(_translate( "MainTab","This is Object 1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction: Changed the line

```
 super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
```

to

```
 super(QWidget, self).__init__()
```

This worked.